# CSS table persistent headers

Tags: css, css-position, tablelayout

I have a table with fixed layout. I added some code to take the thead element out of the flow (position: fixed) to stay on the screen when scrolling the table.

```
table { table-layout:fixed; width: 100% }
table th { width: 50px }
table th:first-child { width: 20em; }

table td { width: 50px }
table tbody tr:first-child td:first-child { width: 20em;}
```

The problem is, when thead is taken out of the flow, the rest of the table column's resize themselves. See http://jsfiddle.net/2EDQR/3/ for reproduction example. Try scrolling the result frame and see how the table columns are squeezing.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

**UPD:** I need the headers to stay in the viewport when I scroll the page. The problem is when the headers are taken out of the flow, the tbody columns are resizing, so the headers do not align with the columns

Comment: There is error in your html code. Some tags are not closed correctly

Comment: It seems to be jsfiddle bug. I beautified that code and there was nothing wrong with it. I've updated it however.

Comment: Do you need fixed headers?

Comment: It's not clear from the question? I need the headers to stay in the viewport when I scroll the page. The problem is when the headers are taken out of the flow, the tbody columns are resizing, so the headers do not align with the columns

Comment: Just get rid of the <thead></thead> and it should work.  like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2EDQR/5/

Answer (score 0):

It works almost fine if you remove `table-layout:fixed;`